# Como utilizar uma const com middlewares e routes?

Tags: node.js, express.js

Possuo a seguinte `const` no meu arquivo **routes.js**:

```
const database = [];
```

Para fins de aprendizagem estou utilizando ela como se fosse o meu **"database"**, onde  de acordo com o tipo de requisição eu manipulo esta variável... Esta variável está no arquivo citado acima e estou utilizando dentro das rotas após o uso de certos **middlewares**.

Utilizando boas práticas eu gostaria de saber como posso utilizar esta variável entre meus **middlewares** e minhas rotas, o que eu tentei fazer foi criar um **middleware global** onde eu fazia o seguinte:

```
res.locals.database = [];
next();
```

Porém este código "apaga" a variável quando se dá a resposta com o **res**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vejo necessidade no uso de middlewares, você pode declarar um módulo como seu banco de dados e acessar esse módulo quando necessário, não precisa anexa-lo no seu `res`.

Por exemplo:

```js
// database.js

const database = {
    users: [],
    messages: []
}

module.exports = database
```

Como em NodeJS os dados persistem em memória (volátil), você pode anexar e remover itens desse "banco" em requisições diferentes.

Agora basta importar esse módulo e utiliza-lo nos seus handlers. Exemplo:

```js
// app.js

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const database = require('./database')

const server = express()
server.use(bodyParser.json())

server.post('/messages', (req, res) => {
    database.messages.push(req.body)
    res.send()
})

server.get('/messages', (req, res) => {
    res.json(database.messages)
})

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Servidor iniciado na porta 3000')
})
```

Na rota `POST` `/messages` você pode enviar uma carga útil para ser anexada no array de `messages`, enquanto na rota `GET` `/messages`, você recupera todas as mensagens. Esses dados irão persistir porque o `database` utilizado para todas as requisições é sempre o mesmo.

Comment: Também é possível encurtar o `database.js` para `module.exports = { /* ... */ }`, já que a variável só é exportada, não precisa dela, basta exportar o objeto literal diretamente, mas a variável pode ser útil para que fique claro que aquele objeto é o banco de dados

Comment: Obrigado aos dois, gostei de ambas as respostas.